# show notifications in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm writing my first chrome extension. In my chrome extension I have added an option in Right Click Context menu.

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "id": "MyExntesion",
  "title": "My Extension",
  "type": "normal",
  "contexts": ["image"],
  "onclick": this.handleClick
});
```

In my handleClick method, I want to show a notification. This notification should pop out in top right corner of the browser window which just confirms that user has clicked on the context menu. How do I do that?

I did some research but didn't find anything useful. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications this talkes about system tray notification, where as this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup lets you create new popups but they are only shown when extension icon is clicked.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are 3 principal ways of showing a notification in Chrome.

1) Aforementioned [`chrome.notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications). It will show a toast (not merely an indication in systray), but you as a developer have little say on how it appears. Usage overview [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications).

[image: Chrome notification]

2) Standard HTML [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification). In Chrome, looks similar to `chrome.notifications`, except for less control over formatting and not managed by Chrome's notification center. Usage overview [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications).

3) If you really want control over how it's shown, the most invasive and hard way is to inject your UI into all pages with a content script.

You face several problems if you do that:

- In general, it's harder to design the UI yourself;
- The UI will be confined to the webpage viewport;
- CSS may bleed from the page and mangle your UI (though Shadow DOM can be an answer);
- You need blanket permissions for "data on all webpages" just to show your UI. It tends to scare users away.

If you decide to go that route nonetheless, here's a question that might help: [Chrome extension content scripts custom ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725770/chrome-extension-content-scripts-custom-ui)

Comment: I don't know if you have used evernote web clipper extension, but are those notifications shown in that extension built using the third option that you suggested?

Comment: But if you are using the option 1 or 2 (I'm trying to use number 2) how do you get the registration_id in order to send push notifications to the chrome browser? And how do you wait for that notifications? Thank you for that answer!

Comment: @eloibm _Displaying_ notifications has absolutely nothing to do with _receiving_ them. Meditate upon `chrome.gcm` **and linked docs**. If you still have questions, ask a new question - don't ask unrelated follow-up questions in comments, that's not the purpose of comments.